# uniswap-python "cannot import name 'Uniswap' from partially initialized module 'uniswap' (most likely due to a circular import)"

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to get familiar with the uniswap-python module, but already stuck at the very first test. This code is from the [getting started guide](https://uniswap-python.com/getting-started.html):

```
from uniswap import Uniswap

address = None          # or None if you're not going to make transactions
private_key = None  # or None if you're not going to make transactions
version = 2                       # specify which version of Uniswap to use
provider = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/c4bcdc3744df4340b875e095b0713258"    # can also be set through the environment variable `PROVIDER`
uniswap = Uniswap(address=address, private_key=private_key, version=version, provider=provider)

# Some token addresses we'll be using later in this guide
eth = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
bat = "0x0D8775F648430679A709E98d2b0Cb6250d2887EF"
dai = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F"

uniswap.get_price_input(eth, dai, 10**18)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\phil\Desktop\Python\uniswap.py", line 1, in <module>
    from uniswap import Uniswap
  File "c:\Users\phil\Desktop\Python\uniswap.py", line 1, in <module>
    from uniswap import Uniswap
ImportError: cannot import name 'Uniswap' from partially initialized module 'uniswap' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\phil\Desktop\Python\uniswap.py)
```

Comment: your file has name `uniswap.py` so now `import uniswap` loads your file instead of module `uniswap`. Rename your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file has name `uniswap.py`

```
c:\Users\phil\Desktop\Python\uniswap.py
```

and now `from uniswap import ...` loads your file instead of module `uniswap`.

Simply rename your file - ie. `test-uniswap.py`.

```
c:\Users\phil\Desktop\Python\test-uniswap.py
```